# Google Maps fails to load with angularjs

Tags: google-maps, angularjs

Hi i've been attempting to load Googlemaps onto the page when the user clicks on the link. I've been attempting to follow [Using google maps with angularjs and angular ui](http://www.ramandv.com/blog/using-google-maps-with-angularjs/) but the map doesn't appear. On localhost, the error i get is: no module:map testing. What does no module here imply? I keep running into such errors. It works on JSfiddle for some reason...[The working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ramandv/xSPAA/).

Html file:

```
  <div ng-app='maptesting'>
    <div ng-controller="MapCtrl">
        <div id="map_canvas" ui-map="myMap" 
        style="height:300px;width:400px;border:2px solid #777777;margin:3px; border:1px solid" 
        ui-options="mapOptions" 
        ui-event="{'map-idle' : 'onMapIdle()'}"
        >
        </div>

        <!--In addition to creating the markers on the map, div elements with existing google.maps.Marker object should be created to hook up with events -->
        <div ng-repeat="marker in myMarkers" ui-map-marker="myMarkers[$index]"
                        ui-event="{'map-click': 'markerClicked(marker)'}">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript file:

```
//Add the requried module 'angular-ui' as a dependency
angular.module('maptesting', ['ui.map','ui.event']);

function MapCtrl($scope) {
    var ll = new google.maps.LatLng(13.0810, 80.2740);
    $scope.mapOptions = {
        center: ll,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    //Markers should be added after map is loaded
    $scope.onMapIdle = function() {
        if ($scope.myMarkers === undefined){    
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: $scope.myMap,
                position: ll
            });
            $scope.myMarkers = [marker, ];
        }
    };

    $scope.markerClicked = function(m) {
        window.alert("clicked");
    };

}
```

Live example:
On plunker: [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/linhS6JSQ3KdMdOOVwTG?p=preview) 
On JSfiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ramandv/xSPAA/).
On another note, would it be better to code the google maps and angularjs integration using angularui, from scratch or using [google maps with angular](http://nlaplante.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/usage)? The anuglarui one looks great but when i tried it it didn't work too. I read in a google circle that it wasn't updated for a while which could be why it isn't working well.

Answer:
Yep all I was missing were the script tags. Namely:

```
 <script src="http://www.flocations.com/static/vendor/angular-ui/event/event.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.flocations.com/static/vendor/angular-ui/map/ui-map.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: suggest you provide a live demo in jsfiddle.net or plunker

Comment: I've edited it to make the links clearer. They were lost in the mess of words. Thanks

Comment: if it works in jsfiddle...must be something different in your local version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Your Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/linhS6JSQ3KdMdOOVwTG?p=preview) doesn't have `<script></script>` elements for `ui.map` or `ui.event`. For example, you might want to include these in your `<head>`:

```
<script src="ui-event.js"></script>
<script src="ui-map.js"></script>
```